# Set value for macro at the beginning of each page

Tags: hooks, shipout, lthooks

I am trying to set the value of a macro at the beginning of each page using `shipout` hooks. Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \g_mymodule_test_tl
\hook_gput_code:nnn { shipout/firstpage } { mymodule }
  {
    \tl_gset:Nn \g_mymodule_test_tl { BEGIN-OF-PAGE }
  }
\hook_gput_code:nnn { shipout/before } { mymodule }
  {
    \tl_gset:Nn \g_mymodule_test_tl { BEGIN-OF-PAGE }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Text

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_use:N \g_mymodule_test_tl
\tl_gset:Nn \g_mymodule_test_tl { RESET }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\clearpage
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_use:N \g_mymodule_test_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

I think there are some mistakes with my code, for example, the macro on the first page is not assigned to the given value `BEGIN-OF-PAGE`. May I ask what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: the shipout is at the *end* of the page building as it pushes out a page.

Comment: If you need it to have the value at the start of your first page, you can set it in the hook at begin document. As @UlrikeFischer already commented, the `shipout` hooks only fire when the page is already built.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you SO MUCH for this clarification!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the variable at begin document (using the `end` hook) and then at `shipout/after`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \g_mymodule_test_tl
\int_new:N \g_mymodule_test_int

\hook_gput_code:nnn { begindocument/end } { mymodule }
  {
    \int_gincr:N \g_mymodule_test_int
    \tl_gset:Ne \g_mymodule_test_tl { BEGIN-OF-PAGE~\int_eval:n { \g_mymodule_test_int } }
  }
\hook_gput_code:nnn { shipout/after } { mymodule }
  {
    \int_gincr:N \g_mymodule_test_int
    \tl_gset:Ne \g_mymodule_test_tl { BEGIN-OF-PAGE~\int_eval:n { \g_mymodule_test_int }}
  }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\showhook}{}{\tl_use:N \g_mymodule_test_tl}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Text \showhook

\lipsum[1-2]

\showhook

\end{document}
```

[image]